# How to run observable depends on previous observable's result with RxJS in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I need to do these things:

- delete an item from remote server
- if it's success, delete item from local storage
- if it's success, reload the items from remote server

Now I have this code, but it's not working well, because the third step isn't run.

```js
delete(model: T, paginate: PaginateInterface): Observable<any> {
  return this.remoteStorageService.delete(model).pipe(map((resultDelete: boolean) => {
    if (resultDelete) {
      this.localStorageService.delete(model);
      return this.remoteStorageService.getAll().pipe(map( (resultGetAll: PaginateInterface) => {
        return resultGetAll;
      }));
    }

    return paginate;
  }));
}
```

I tried to use RxJS switchMap function, but I'm totally lost.

How can I run a function depends on observable's result, and then another observable what return with results?

Comment: does your api return boolean value ? can you add the code you tried with switchMap ?
in case your api fail, doesn't it return error response status code (500, 400 etcc... ) ?

Comment: Which is the return type of `this.localStorageService`?

Comment: yeah, the implementation depends on what the server returns when a delete operation is unsuccessful (error notification with 400? code or 200 with some objects inside?)

Comment: @Munzer the remoteStorageService handle all of the errors. On this point of the program it's unneccesary thing.

Comment: @Picci `this.localStorageService.delete()` is  a void function - it's handle the possible errors inside itself.

Comment: @martin as you see here isn't any server communication. Here is only two services. `remoteStorageService` and `localStorageService`. The `localStorageService`'s delete function is a void. The `remoteStorageService.delete()` return as boolean.

Comment: so `this.remoteStorageService.delete()` is not returning an Observable?

Comment: Your backend service must return the status code accordingly, so the observable fail when the status code is not success code, that way you wouldn't care about the return, anyways you didn't answer me, does it return a Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I assume steps 1 and 3 are the component's job and step 2 is the service's job.

You can use the `tap` method to do extra logic on success or failure of an observable:

Service:

```
deleteItem(model): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.delete<any>(`${yourUrl}`, model)
    .pipe(
      tap(result => {
        // success
        // delete from local storage here
      }, error => {
        // fail
        // in case you need logic for failure, put it here
      })
    );
}
```

Component:

```
delete(model) {
  this.yourService.deleteItem(model)
    .subscribe(result => {
      // success, local storage is updated at this point
      // reload your data
    }, error => {
      // fail, local storage was not updated
      // do your error handling logic here
    });
}
```

If step 2 needs to be done in the component, simply move the `pipe` code to your component.

Comment: this code is inside a service, what's handle the deleting process. Give order to the `remoteStorageService.delete()` and if it's success, call the `localStorageService.delete()` too. And then call the `remoteStorageService.getAll()` too. But the last two steps happening only when the first is returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted and the comments I assume that `remoteStorageService.delete` and `remoteStorageService.getAll()` return some Observables while `localStorageService.delete()` returns `void`.

If this is the case you can try something like this

```
delete(model: T, paginate: PaginateInterface): Observable<any> {
  return this.remoteStorageService.delete(model)
  .pipe(
     concatMap((resultDelete: boolean) => {
        if (resultDelete) {
           this.localStorageService.delete(model);
           return this.remoteStorageService.getAll();
        } else {
           return EMPTY  // if the delete fails you complete the Observable
           // you can also error here if you want to terminate the Observable with an error
        }
     })
  )
}
```

The key here is that first you execute `remoteStorageService.delete` and wait for the Observable to notify its result. The use of the operator `concatMap` ensures that the Observables contained within `concatMap` are executed (or more precisely subscribed) only after `remoteStorageService.delete` notifies its result. You can use then the result of `remoteStorageService.delete` to decide whether to return `remoteStorageService.getAll()` or return `EMPTY`.

In the first case, `remoteStorageService.getAll()` will be the Observable subscribed by the Component, in the second case `EMPTY` will be the Observable subscribed by the Component. `EMPY` is an Observable which does not emit anything and immediately terminates.